# How to deal with Xing-login plugin for a domain with www and with out www?

Tags: php, xing

I am using xing-login plugin for signup/login on my website. I have a consumer key for domain without `www.`
But when I tried to login via `www.domainName` it gives an error saying that the consumer key is invalid.
Is it possible to make a key work for both domains?

Comment: Can you get a consumer key for the domain with www? Does longin without www work? What have you tried? It's difficult to tell what is being asked here, and this question cannot be
reasonably answered in its current form. Please provide the context, and/or post
code samples of what you have done 
(i.e.: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com))

Comment: @RobBricheno  if i get consumer key with www then it works with www.domainName BUT  it does not work without www .  And if i get key without www then only works without www and does not work with www.domainName.